# Do the poles of the $\Gamma(z)$ multiply out to 1 in some way?

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, analytic-continuation

Is there a meaningful way to assign values $\Gamma^\star(z)$ related to the values of the gamma function $\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty {e^{-t}t^{-z}dt}$  such that $\prod\limits_{ \Bbb Z^-} \Gamma^\star (z) = \Gamma^\star(1)$?

Intuitively, I feel like they *should* because of the recursive relation and fact that $\Gamma(0) = 1$. Perhaps $\Gamma^\star$ is related to residues or Cauchy principle values?

Otherwise, is there a good proof that $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0}({\prod\limits_{\Bbb Z^-}{\Gamma(z + \epsilon)}}) = 1$ that doesn't just use the recursive definition?

I wasn't sure of the right terminology to use so please let me know if this is too soft and I won't mind closing it.

Comment: The product of what multiplies out to $1$?

Comment: How do you define $Γ^{\small\pmb\star} (x)$ because the values at the poles of $Γ(x)$ would just diverge to $\pm \infty$?

Comment: @TymaGaidash that's basically what my question is. Is there a function $\Gamma^\star$ related in any way to $\Gamma $ such that the property holds?